# Remove parent element in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

#### Problem:

I want to remove a parent element of my array with a condition.

#### Input

```
$myArray = array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'ulStatic' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'day' => '2019-03-30 18:30:00',
          'id' => '7',
          'origin' => 'intentions',
        ),
      ),
      'ulDynamic' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'day' => '2019-03-30 18:30:00',
          'id' => '5',
          'origin' => 'intentions',
        ),
      ),
      'ulCreatedDynamic' =>
      array (
      ),
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'ulStatic' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'day' => '2019-03-31 09:30:00',
          'id' => '8',
          'origin' => 'intentions',
        ),
      ),
      'ulDynamic' =>
      array (
      ),
      'ulCreatedDynamic' =>
      array (
      ),
    ),
    2 =>
    array (
      'ulStatic' =>
      array (
      ),
      'ulDynamic' =>
      array (
      ),
      'ulCreatedDynamic' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          'day' => '2019-04-02 11:15:00',
          'id' => '275',
          'origin' => 'obseques',
        ),
        1 =>
        array (
          'day' => '2019-04-02 11:15:00',
          'id' => '277',
          'origin' => 'obseques',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

In this array, I want to remove in associative array named `ulCreatedDynamic` the key that contains `id = 275` and `day = '2019-04-02 11:15:00'`;

So this key have to remove:

```
0 =>
    array (
      'day' => '2019-04-02 11:15:00',
      'id' => '275',
      'origin' => 'obseques',
    ),
```

#### Attempt:

```
$id = 275;
$day = "2019-04-02 11:15:00";

foreach($myArray as $array):
    foreach($array as $ul => $v):
        if($ul == "ulCreatedDynamic"):
            foreach($v as $elementKey => $element):
                if($element['day'] == $day && $element['id'] == $id):
                    unset($v[$elementKey]);
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump or echo `$elementKey` inside your loop? or `$ul`?  These are critical troubleshooting skills that will almost certainly help you find the issue on your own...

Comment: var_dump($elementKey) => int(0)
var_dump($ul) => string(16) "ulCreatedDynamic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach($some_array as $item)` will copy the entire array on the fly as soon as any item is changed. You need to work on a reference using the `&` operator instead.

```
foreach($myArray as &$array):
  foreach($array as $ul => &$v):
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is what you might want to achieve. I'm pretty sure there are much easier ways to solve your problem.

Probably, you are not unsetting from your main array, `$myArray`, in this line: `unset($v[$elementKey]);`

```
$myArray = array(
    0 => array(
        'ulStatic' => array(
            0 => array(
                'day' => '2019-03-30 18:30:00',
                'id' => '7',
                'origin' => 'intentions',
            ),
        ),
        'ulDynamic' => array(
            0 => array(
                'day' => '2019-03-30 18:30:00',
                'id' => '5',
                'origin' => 'intentions',
            ),
        ),
        'ulCreatedDynamic' => array(
        ),
    ),
    1 => array(
        'ulStatic' => array(
            0 => array(
                'day' => '2019-03-31 09:30:00',
                'id' => '8',
                'origin' => 'intentions',
            ),
        ),
        'ulDynamic' => array(
        ),
        'ulCreatedDynamic' => array(
        ),
    ),
    2 => array(
        'ulStatic' => array(
        ),
        'ulDynamic' => array(
        ),
        'ulCreatedDynamic' => array(
            0 => array(
                'day' => '2019-04-02 11:15:00',
                'id' => '275',
                'origin' => 'obseques',
            ),
            1 => array(
                'day' => '2019-04-02 11:15:00',
                'id' => '277',
                'origin' => 'obseques',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

$id = 275;
$day = "2019-04-02 11:15:00";

foreach ($myArray as $k => $array):
    foreach ($array as $ul => $v):
        if ($ul == "ulCreatedDynamic"):
            foreach ($v as $elementKey => $element):
                if ($element['day'] == $day && $element['id'] == $id):
                    // unset($v[$elementKey]);
                    unset($myArray[$k][$ul][$elementKey]);
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
var_dump($myArray);
```

#### $myArray:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ulStatic"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["day"]=>
        string(19) "2019-03-30 18:30:00"
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["origin"]=>
        string(10) "intentions"
      }
    }
    ["ulDynamic"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["day"]=>
        string(19) "2019-03-30 18:30:00"
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["origin"]=>
        string(10) "intentions"
      }
    }
    ["ulCreatedDynamic"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ulStatic"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["day"]=>
        string(19) "2019-03-31 09:30:00"
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "8"
        ["origin"]=>
        string(10) "intentions"
      }
    }
    ["ulDynamic"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["ulCreatedDynamic"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ulStatic"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["ulDynamic"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["ulCreatedDynamic"]=>
    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["day"]=>
        string(19) "2019-04-02 11:15:00"
        ["id"]=>
        string(3) "277"
        ["origin"]=>
        string(8) "obseques"
      }
    }
  }
}
```